# Serial Ports /dev/tty.* are not working when /dev/cu.* ports are accessed firstly

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port, processing

I am trying to create a Processing application connected with an Arduino.

Due to the fact that I want the connection between the two to be established automatically, meaning that I do not specify the name of the port, but I'm using Serial.list() to get the names of the ports available and then with a for loop I will check which one is printing the correct string.

The problem is that when I access firstly the `/dev/cu.*` then all the `/dev/tty.*` ports are busy and vice versa. This is quite strange and I do not want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one(`/dev/tty.*`) or the other(`/dev/cu.*`), but not both at the same time as they might point to the same resource in different ways.

I recommend listing the ports, checking the port prefix (agains let's say `/dev/tty.*`, but not `/dev/cu.*`), initialising the Serial port, then exiting the loop that traverses the listed serial ports:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial arduino;
final int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

void setup(){
  String[] ports = Serial.list();

  for(int i = 0 ; i < ports.length; i++){//go through each port
    if(ports[i].contains("tty.usbmodem")){//find one that looks like an Arduino on OSX

      try{
        arduino = new Serial(this,ports[i],BAUD_RATE);//initialize the connection
        i = ports.length;//exit the loop, break; should also work
        println("Arduino connection succesfully initialized");
      }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error opening Serial port!\nPlease check USB connection and ensure the port is not already open in another application.");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
  }

  if(arduino == null) System.err.println("Serial connection to Arduino failed!");
}
```